# Как в VS Code переместить панель вправо?

Tags: visual-studio-code

В просто студии все достаточно легко, но для Visual Studio Code я ни нашел упоминаний в документации, не нашел дополнений для этого.

Как можно переместить браузер вправо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Браузер файлов можно перекинуть вправо через меню `View` - `Move Side Bar Right`.

Comment: Я слеп, спасибо. А может быть ещё подскажете, как сделать так, чтобы в браузере папки открывались по двойному клику?

Comment: @Fangog такой настройки, похоже, пока нет. Вот [тут](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9388) реквест на добавление этой фичи.

Answer (score 1):

С `VSCode version 1.64` появилась возможность кастомизировать layout'ы с помощью графического интерфейса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка для `Primary Side Bar Position` -> `Right`

В [доке к оф.релизу](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_customize-layout-control) можно в гифках посмотреть, как это работает.